# Laravel API Resource with multiple level Sub Resources

Tags: laravel

I am working on Laravel apis, I am having some issues with a multi level resource query. I want to get a json responce of with the following.

Trip->withRoutes->withCollectionPoints->withTripCollections for the trip (api/v1/trips/{id}).

When I run this I get the info filtering down up to trip collections. I get all collections instead of those that belong to the parent current CollectionPoint see info below.

```
"data": {
        "id": 28,
        "route": {
            "id": 17,
            "name": "Route Nongoma",
            "route_group_id": 31,
            "collectionPoints": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "sequence": 1,
                    "client_id": 4,
                    "client": "Tremblay and Sons",
                    "trip_collections": [
                        {
                            "id": 27,
                            "trip_id": 26,
                            "starting_kms": 2581,
                            "ending_kms": 2600,
                            "collection_date": "2023-04-23T23:52:00.000000Z",
                            "client_id": 4,
                            "collections": "36",
                            "deliveries": "0",
                            "status": "COMPLETE"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 29,
                            "trip_id": 28,
                            "starting_kms": 256321,
                            "ending_kms": 257000,
                            "collection_date": "2023-04-24T09:26:00.000000Z",
                            "client_id": 4,
                            "collections": "20",
                            "deliveries": "0",
                            "status": "COMPLETE"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 30,
                            "trip_id": 29,
                            "starting_kms": 5120,
                            "ending_kms": 5130,
                            "collection_date": "2023-04-24T14:33:00.000000Z",
                            "client_id": 4,
                            "collections": "3",
                            "deliveries": "0",
                            "status": "COMPLETE"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "sequence": 2,
                    "client_id": 5,
                    "client": "Yundt and Sons",
                    "trip_collections": [
                        {
                            "id": 28,
                            "trip_id": 26,
                            "starting_kms": 2581,
                            "ending_kms": 2900,
                            "collection_date": "2023-04-24T03:38:00.000000Z",
                            "client_id": 5,
                            "collections": "1",
                            "deliveries": "1",
                            "status": "COMPLETE"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "sequence": 3,
                    "client_id": 6,
                    "client": "Koch, Jones and Kris",
                    "trip_collections": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "sequence": 2,
                    "client_id": 4,
                    "client": "Tremblay and Sons",
                    "trip_collections": []
                }
            ]
        },
```

It goes to this TripApiResource

```
 public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "route_id" => $this->route_id,
            "route_group_id" => $this->route_group_id,
            "route" => new RouteResource($this->route),
            "completed_collections" => $this->tripCollections->count(),
            "trip_collections" => TripCollectionResource::collection($tripCollections),
        ];
    }
```

So the issue is that , the results that are returned for the trip_collections include data that does not belong to the specified trip id. See below

```
"collectionPoints": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "sequence": 1,
                    "client_id": 4,
                    "client": "Tremblay and Sons",
                    "trip_collections": [
                        {
                            "id": 27,
                            "trip_id": 26,
                            "starting_kms": 2581,
                            "ending_kms": 2600,
                            "collection_date": "2023-04-23T23:52:00.000000Z",
                            "client_id": 4,
                            "collections": "36",
                            "deliveries": "0",
                            "status": "COMPLETE"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 29,
                            "trip_id": 28,
                            "starting_kms": 256321,
                            "ending_kms": 257000,
                            "collection_date": "2023-04-24T09:26:00.000000Z",
                            "client_id": 4,
                            "collections": "20",
                            "deliveries": "0",
                            "status": "COMPLETE"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 30,
                            "trip_id": 29,
                            "starting_kms": 5120,
                            "ending_kms": 5130,
                            "collection_date": "2023-04-24T14:33:00.000000Z",
                            "client_id": 4,
                            "collections": "3",
                            "deliveries": "0",
                            "status": "COMPLETE"
                        }
                    ]
```

This is the RouteResource

```
 public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "name" => $this->name,
            "collectionPoints" => CollectionPointResource::collection($this->collectionPoints),
        ];
    }
```

This is the CollectionPointResource

```
public function toArray($request): array
    {
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "sequence" => $this->sequence,
            "client_id" => $this->client_id,
            "client" => $this->client->name,
            "trip_collections" => TripCollectionResource::collection($this->tripCollections),
        ];
    }
```

Finally, the TripCollectionReource

```
public function toArray($request): array
    {
        return
            [
                "id" => $this->id,
                "trip_id" => $this->trip_id,
                "starting_kms" => $this->starting_kms,
                "ending_kms" => $this->ending_kms,
                "collection_date" => $this->collection_date,
                "client_id" => $this->client_id,
                "collections" => $this->collections,
                "deliveries" => $this->deliveries,
                "status" => $this->status,
            ];
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong?

Comment: The issue is that , the results returned include records that do not belong to the specified trip_id parameter

Comment: And what if you do it like `$trip->with(['routes', 'collection_points', 'trip_collections'])`??